# Finding Post which don't belong to Author in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have a Post Model like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And the User model looks like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy

  # I have used devise gem for User management
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
         :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:login]
end
```

Then Lets Say `X` and `Y` And `Z` created a Post using their accounts.
If `X` is logged in I can clearly show his Post in Views by just doing this:

```
current_user.post
```

But for some reason I also want the post which don't belongs to `X` or lets say `arbitrary user`??
Is there some way where i can take `current_user` object and pass some method or something like that??

I simply mean i want to get a post except than a particular user or for example current_user (user who is logged in)
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `Post` _has many_ `posts`, is what u have, or you mistyped?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Sorry It was mistyped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But for some reason I also want the post which don't belongs to X or lets say arbitrary user?

You can use a scope to fetch *posts* for any specific users like below:

```
scope :fetch_by_user, ->(user) { where(user: user }
```

Then call it from any where like from your controller, as below :

```
Post.fetch_by_user(another_user_object)
```

*update*

If you want to list all posts which are not by current user, add a scope like:

```
scope :posts_by_not_current_user, ->(user) { where.not(user: user) }
```

Now call from controller.

```
Post.posts_by_not_current_user(current_user)
```

P.S: The scope has to be added inside the `Post` model.

Comment: so in another_user_object i pass current_user ?

Comment: @aftershock It can be any user object. That is any object which is an instance of `User`.

Comment: So how can i get the object of user which is except other than current user?? Simply i mean how do i grab those users which is not current user ?

Comment: @aftershock `User.where(id: current_user.id)` will give you what you asked.

Comment: current_user.id will give currently logged in user , isn't it? how i get those other user id which is not logged in (current_user.id )

Comment: @aftershock Look the answer now as per your comment. Please learn first how to ask a good question, that helps both parties.

Comment: Thanks Arup problem fixed:) btw you are missing closing } . Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will have to write a custom query.

```
Post.where('user_id IN (#{current_user.id}, #{another_user.id})')
```

Comment: There Can many users LIKE A , B , C , D ...... I want the post from those user which is not current user lets say X. How do i grab those other user? thanks

Comment: @punit SQL injection can happen in your query. Don't advice this answer. You can write it other way also.